# Lost connection with HTTPS

Tags: session, https

I'm writing a web client that needs to deal with lost connection.

If you are connected to a server using HTTPS and Internet connection drops, will the server lose the session information?

Once Internet connection is restored, does the client need to re-login to the server or does it depend on the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the server determines how long a session lives (by defining a session timeout) and how a session (if at all) is persisted between single requests. The server sends a cookie with the session information (a session key) back to the client, so when the client sends the next request including the session cookie, the server knows which session to use.

Having said is - there is no information between two requests, whether the internet connection was lost in the meantime. As long as the server still has the session and the client still has the corresponding cookie, everything should work as expected.

On the other hand, even if there was no interrupt in the connection at all and both server and client were up and running, but without talking to each other (i.e. without requests), the session might be lost because of a simple timeout on the server side.

So on the server you might receive requests for resources that are secured or need a certain session state - and there is no such session. And on the client side you always might receive responses that indicate that a login is necessary.

Both cases must be implemented properly.

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP protocol itself is **stateless** i.e. each request is served as is without any relation to previous of future requests.

To overcome this you can use client Cookies. Your cookie can keep a session state identifier which can be sent back to the server after a connection drop to resume the previous state.

In addition to that you can build a session management module which handles session persistence.

Answer (score 1):

first it depends on the type of session you are talking:

- ssl session
  This can cause an shortend renegotiation. If the Server support it.
  That mean it save CPU time.
- http sessions
  here it does not only depend on the server but also on your web page code.
  For example if the session drop's while delivering the page conntent.
  The servlet receive an connection reset during flush and may invalidate the session.
- Also id depends if the session is bound to the ip adress. Than it depends if the
  new connection use the same ip adress.

There is no simple answer as you maybe expected. Since it depends on to many points.

Answer (score 1):

As the others already stated you can "persist" a connection by using a SessionID, which is recommended to be stored in a cookie. Most of the modern Environments like PHP and ASP.NET use this mechanism which can deal with lost connections.

Please refer to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet for security considerations for implementing a secure Session Management.

Additionally what you can do with SSL is to build the Session Management using client certificates. The user is identified by the unique certificate which is issued to him. This has the advantages that the client does not have to login first. On the other hand you have to issue a client cert to every client, which might be complex.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies to store the session information, once connection is lost you can easily get the information from the cookies. call  the cookies using condition i.e. if session lost call for the cookie. use Php to store information in the session and call the cookie